# MySQL: rescheduling events from a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures

I'm trying to fire a mysql event to react to real world events.

Setup:
I've created a persistent event and I'm trying to reschedule it from a stored procedure.

In the stored procedure I calculate a timestamp and store it in l_EndDateTime.

```
  ALTER EVENT MyEvent
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 4 HOUR STARTS l_EndDateTime
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE;
```

This gives error 1054 saying it's not a valid column.

After reading this comment:

> The ON SCHEDULE clause may use expressions involving built-in MySQL
>   functions and user variables to obtain any of the timestamp or
>   interval values which it contains. You cannot use stored routines or
>   user-defined functions in such expressions, and you cannot use any
>   table references; however, you can use SELECT FROM DUAL. This is true
>   for both ALTER EVENT and CREATE EVENT statements. Beginning with MySQL
>   5.1.13, references to stored routines, user-defined functions, and tables in such cases are specifically not permitted, and fail with an
>   error (see Bug #22830).

I tried this:

```
  ALTER EVENT MyEvent
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 4 HOUR STARTS (SELECT l_EndDateTime FROM DUAL)
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE;
```

Which gives a different error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **a user variable** instead of stored procedure level variable

```
SET @l_EndDateTime = NOW();
ALTER EVENT MyEvent
   ON SCHEDULE EVERY 4 HOUR STARTS @l_EndDateTime
   ON COMPLETION PRESERVE;
```

That will work just fine.

Comment: I never thought to try that. I'm surprised the kind of variable makes a difference. Thanks again